# Would this question about Aramaic be on topic?

Tags: discussion

> Which modern day dialect of Aramaic is the closest one to the dialect that Jesus of Nazareth spoke in Palestine some 2000 years ago?

Would this question be on topic on the main site?

Comment: Sure, it would be on topic.